# Using CSS to make sections that extend full width of screen

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is real simple but it's been a few yeasr since I've worked in CSS and need some help jogging my brain. I simply want to create a number of sections (i.e., ) where each one will have a different background color and each section will stretch to the edge of the browser window. I've provided a basic scheme as follows:

```
    <body>

<div class="header">
    <header>
        Header content.
    </header>
</div>

<div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="content-blue">
    <p>…content…</p>
</div>

<div class="content-red">
    <p>...content...</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <footer>
        Footer content.
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
```

the CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body { background: yellow; }

div.header { background: orange; color: white; }

div.nav { background: pink; }

div.content-blue { background: blue; color: white; }

div.content-red { background: red; color: white; }

div.footer { background: gray; color: white; }
```

And yes, I did take a look through the forums and look around but I couldn't find anything particularly related. Maybe my question's too simple. :)

Comment: what if you set `div.nav {width: 100%;}` ? Problem it might be restricted by the body, the body needs also to have a width of 100%.

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: Your scheme seems to work perfectly. You just need to remove the padding from the body. No need to set the width of the divs, since they are block elements will automatically use the width available. If I make a code snippet with your code in it, it works perfectly (at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a

```
min-width: 100%;
```

to the relevant divs

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body { background: yellow; }

.header, .nav, .content-blue, .content-red, .footer {
min-width: 100%;
}

div.header { background: orange; color: white; }

div.nav { background: pink; }

div.content-blue { background: blue; color: white; }

div.content-red { background: red; color: white; }

div.footer { background: gray; color: white; }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <header>
        Header content.
    </header>
</div>

<div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="content-blue">
    <p>…content…</p>
</div>

<div class="content-red">
    <p>...content...</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <footer>
        Footer content.
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Renders at 100% width for me - is that what you were after?

Comment: My idea was to make sections, each one with a different bgcolor/font color. I'd use media queries/rwd to make it collapse on mobile. I just wanted no space between sections (i.e., divs) and to make all elements extend to browser window.

Comment: Ok. Made some progress but I'm having some issues with media queries. Some how when the screen moves under 600px it's not switching over to the mobile style. Is there something I'm missing? http://ramadaan.rocks/test.html?nocache=1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything apart from removing the padding on the body, which you already did.

You just need to remove the padding from the body.

There is need to set the width of the divs, since they are block elements so they will automatically use the width available.

If I make a code snippet with your code in it, it works perfectly (at least in Chrome):

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body { background: yellow; }

div.header { background: orange; color: white; }

div.nav { background: pink; }

div.content-blue { background: blue; color: white; }

div.content-red { background: red; color: white; }

div.footer { background: gray; color: white; }
```

```html
    <body>

<div class="header">
    <header>
        Header content.
    </header>
</div>

<div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="content-blue">
    <p>…content…</p>
</div>

<div class="content-red">
    <p>...content...</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <footer>
        Footer content.
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. So when I insert the nav <div> which is comprised of an <ul>, it does not extend to the browser screen. I think this is where I was hitting a wall. [link]http://ramadaan.rocks/test.html